# ImageButton doesnt work Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android

ImageButton doesnt work when I change the visibility to visible. The only visible thing is something like a small shadow (which works like a imagebutton) but the image doesnt show up. All images are added to the project.

main activity:

```
    Button search;
    EditText searchLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        search = findViewById(R.id.buttonSearchAll);

        searchLocation = findViewById(R.id.editLocation);
        

        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String str = searchLocation.getText().toString().trim();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("message", str);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
```

main activity2:

```
    TextView noResults, searched;
    ImageButton btHotel1, btHotel2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        btHotel1 = findViewById(R.id.btHotel1);
        btHotel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btHotel2 = findViewById(R.id.btHotel2);
        btHotel2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        noResults = findViewById(R.id.tvNoResults);


        btHotel1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity3.class));
            }
        });
        btHotel2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity3.class));
            }
        });


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        searched.setText(str);

        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("vienna")){
            btHotel2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //but there's only a small shadow
            return;
        }


        noResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }
}
```

Im not sure why it doesnt work.

Comment: What is in `layout.activity_main2`?

Comment: 1 x TextView (visible), 1 x TextView (gone), 2 x ImageButton (gone)

Comment: Post the entire layout code, please

Answer (score 0):

You call

```
btHotel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

it means view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes

Try to use [View.Invisible](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#INVISIBLE) instead of View.GONE

If you want to make your button visible, use [View.VISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#VISIBLE)!

Comment: still looks the same - the image doesnt show up

Answer (score 0):

First of all where is layout.activity_main2? and Secondly your button is set to View.invisible you should change it to View.visible.